# Check if all rows in a Table have certain values in a few columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a Table **[TableABC]** with column values as shown below. Let's say the Data in that Table is always 6 rows. The column values however changes from day to day. I want to point out that in reality, in TableABC, the [Status] and [SubStatus] has at least a dozen unique values.

**Scenario #1 (Expected Result: Enter the ELSE Block)**

```
ID | Name    | Status      | SubStatus
1  | Abbey   | In Sync     | Same
2  | Abraham | In Sync     | Not Same
3  | Noah    | Not In Sync | Not Same
4  | Simon   | Not In Sync | Same
5  | Peter   | In Sync     | Same
6  | Koi     | In Sync     | Same
```

**Scenario #2 (Expected Result: Enter the ELSE Block)**

```
ID | Name    | Status      | SubStatus
1  | Abbey   | In Sync     | Not Same
2  | Abraham | In Sync     | Not Same
3  | Noah    | In Sync     | Not Same
4  | Simon   | In Sync     | Not Same
5  | Peter   | In Sync     | Not Same
6  | Koi     | In Sync     | Not Same
```

**Scenario #3 (Expected Result: Enter the ELSE Block)**

```
ID | Name    | Status      | SubStatus
1  | Abbey   | Not In Sync | Same
2  | Abraham | Not In Sync | Same
3  | Noah    | Not In Sync | Same
4  | Simon   | Not In Sync | Same
5  | Peter   | Not In Sync | Same
6  | Koi     | Not In Sync | Same
```

**Scenario #4 (Expected Result: Enter the IF Block)**

```
ID | Name    | Status      | SubStatus
1  | Abbey   | In Sync     | Same
2  | Abraham | In Sync     | Same
3  | Noah    | In Sync     | Same
4  | Simon   | In Sync     | Same
5  | Peter   | In Sync     | Same
6  | Koi     | In Sync     | Same
```

I want to write a IF clause such that it goes inside the IF Block when **all rows** in the Table have **[Status] = 'In Sync'** and **[SubStatus] = 'Same'**. So in my example, I want Scenario #4 to get picked up in my IF Clause whereas Scenario #1, #2 & #3 should go into the ELSE Block.

In other words, I want to write a IF Clause like this

```sql
IF (some condition on [TableABC])
  PRINT 'All Rows in the [TableABC] have [Status] = In Sync -and- [SubStatus] = Same'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Some Rows in the [TableABC] may have [Status] <> In Sync -and/or- [SubStatus] <> Same'
```

I appreciate any help that I could get. Thank you.

Comment: `EXISTS` seems to be *exactly* what you want. Just `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableABC WHERE SubStatus NOT IN ('Same','In Sync'))`

Comment: It's still not clear what exactly you want. Can you post some sample data and sample output that reflects how the `if` condition will actually manifest?

Comment: its neither sql nor plsql what you are asking for ?? what is it???

Comment: @nikhilsugandh: It is SQL. I would know, I framed the question. If you read through my Problem Statement (all of it) and then refer to Larnu's answers, you'd be able to understand.

Comment: Don't replace actual text with images... This qusetion is worse that it started as now.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit @Larnu. Btw, the NOT EXISTS does not really work for Scenario #2 & #3.

Comment: Scenario 3 and 4 didn't exist when I made that comment, @GaryTheBrave ...

Comment: @Larnu: Yeah I know. Basically wanted to show all the different possibilities of Data. In the end, Scenario #4 is the only time I want the IF Block Code to be executed and any other combinations it should go into the ELSE Block Code. I can come up with more scenarios but these 4 should be the most basic of all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wanted to post the answer to my question. I got some hints from @DRapp & @Larnu. Thanks to you both and everyone else for helping. Much appreciated.

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[TableABC] a
               WHERE a.[Status] <> 'In Sync' OR a.[SubStatus] <> 'Same')
    PRINT 'All Rows in the [TableABC] have [Status] = In Sync -and- [SubStatus] = Same'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Some Rows in the [TableABC] may have [Status] <> In Sync -and/or- [SubStatus] <> Same';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
select top 1 a.* 
   from TableABC a
   where a.Status != 'In Sync'
      OR a.SubStatus != 'Same'
```

As soon as it hits the first record with EITHER column not having the expected values it will return.  If ALL records have respectively the 'In Sync' and 'Same', NO records will be returned.

Comment: I wanted to perform some sql code IF ALL records have Status = 'In Sync' and SubStatus = 'Same'. Your query gives me a select. Can you frame it in an IF Clause? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @GaryTheBrave, what is the ultimate goal you are trying to get at.  A final presentation to the user?  What is the final purpose that you think you NEED an IF condition within the query.  If I was doing, I would run the query and get either 1 record or none.  If 1, then in the application, just say All are in synch with same value. vs Someone is not in synch with others.  What is it  you really are trying to get out.   Edit your original question and give context of WHY your output desire vs just requiring an IF.  Also, show the if blocks you THINK you need.

Comment: I have quite a bit of operation to be done in the IF block, like deleting a row in another table and then Reseeding it etc. It's a big project and I was stuck at this part. It would not make sense to draw out the entire project. I just needed an answer to my problem. And your answer was close. Thanks for your help. Please see my answer if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select (case when min(status) = max(status) as min(status) = 'In Sync' and
                  min(substatus) = 'Same'
             then 'All in sync and same'
             else 'Some different'
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: the use of `as` in rows 1 & 2 should be `and` I think and a equal symbol is missing

Answer (score 0):

Using a "conditional aggregate" (basically a case expression inside sum) you can determine if that are all identical, plus - if wanted - know how many rows are different.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN diff_rows > 0 THEN concat(diff_rows, ' rows are different')
    ELSE 'All in sync and same'
  END AS Result
FROM (
    SELECT
      SUM (CASE
             WHEN STATUS = 'In Sync' AND substatus = 'Same' THEN 0
             ELSE 1
           END) AS diff_rows
    FROM mytable
) AS derived
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=239a574602181e124ef08cc7df82ea7c)*